# Are generated files persisted on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App, which will generate pdf files at runtime and write them to disk.  **Can I trust that these files will be persisted?**

I am concerned that if my image is spun down and brought back up again then the files might have disappeared.

Or perhaps Azure decides to move the website to a different machine or different datacentre, where these files would not exist.

I know there are cloud based options such as blob storage, but I would prefer the simplicity of writing to disk and having access over FTP.

Answer (score 5):

Anything that you write under the `d:\home` folder is guaranteed to be persisted. See the File System section in [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#persisted-files) for more details on this topic.

Comment: And I take it you mean distributed and persisted?  If the file is created on one machine then it is created on all machines?

Comment: That is correct. It's using a shared file system, so there really is only one instance of the files, accessed by all instances of the Web App.